# OpenCV / JavaCV create new rectangular image from selected quad within image

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I created a java application which displays images and lets the user select any area within this image using 4 points.

What I want to do now is to take this selected quad and create a new rectangular image from it, but OpenCV keeps giving me: *OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat*  at cvPerspectiveTransform

This is my Code:

```
IplImage i2 = IplImage.createFrom(bTmp); 
tmpImage = new IplImage(i2.width()*i2.height());
CvMat m = CvMat.create(3, 3);

cvGetPerspectiveTransform(new float[]{0,0,20,0,20,20,0,20}, new float[]{0,0,20,0,203,20,20,203}, m);
cvPerspectiveTransform(i2, tmpImage, m);
```

any ideas?

Comment: I figured out cvWarpPerspective is probably the method I was looking for, but using it results in the same error message.

Comment: I don't know why, but tmpImage = i2.clone(); fixed it

Comment: Try to create your other image with `tmpImage = i2.clone()`